# Rails3/4 load path for class tweak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, autoload

I'm trying to add a method to the DateTime class like so:

```
class DateTime
  def ymd(sep = "/")
    strftime("%Y#{sep}%m#{sep}%d")
  end
end
```

I put this in `#{config.root}/lib/datetime.rb` and updated the `autoload_path` to include `#{config.root}/lib` (since that seems to go in and out of the conventional autoload path). That didn't work, so I also tried putting it in a random directory (`#{config.root}/blah` and added that path to the autoload_paths line in the config).

In all of the above cases, I'm only able to use the new method in the rails console if I `require 'datetime'` first, and I'm not able to use it in controllers or view templates no matter what I do.

So,

1. Should the file be called `datetime.rb` or `date_time.rb`? (I've tried both so far and neither are currently working)
2. Where should I be putting this file so I can use the new method in models, controllers and views?
3. Any idea why I can `require` it in the console, but it doesn't autoload there?

The app is currently running rails 3.2.21, but I'll switch to rails 4 at some point so answers for either version are appreciated.

Comment: I like to put monkey patches in `config/initializers/class_name.rb`.  They're usually best avoided, but the ability to have them if you need them is part of what makes ruby great and `config/initializers/` is a natural place to look for where runtime changes are being made.

Comment: @ihaztehcodez Gave that a shot, and while it works for the ralis console, both the controller and views still complain that the method doesn't exist. 

(edit: because I think of DateTime and ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone  as the same thing so frequently that I forgot they're different, so yes, this works great. Thanks!)